# Compress string of bits in place (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function that compresses a string of 0's and 1's. That is, "00010111100101" goes to "30104100101". Should this be a very complicated procedure? My code is looking messy.

The prototype should look like:

```
static void compress_bitstring(std::string& str) { 
   // compression algorithm
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you already have.

Comment: It should not be a very complicated procedure, no. I hope this answer to your question helps.

Comment: If you compress that way, it will probably be pretty complicated. I would interpret your output "30104100101" as "3 zeros, followed by 1 zero, followed by 4 ones, followed by 1 zero", in fact I'm not sure precisely what logic you're using to compress. What I would do is, since you know that runs of 1 and 0 will alternate, "00010111100101" would go to "031142111" where the first character indicates that the string starts with a 0, there are 3 of them, then 1 one, then 1 zero, then 4 ones, etc.

Comment: @VyassaBaratham the logic is to never compress lengths of 1 or 2... and since 2, 3, ... are not valid symbols in a binary string, distinguishing "run lengths" from binary digits becomes trivial. So something like 30104100101 has a unique decoding of 00010111100101.

Comment: by 0&1 do you mean to say Binary ? and yes ofcourse show the code to explain well that what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @user2623390: You should realize that we're not here to DO your homework (or refine your homework), but to help with specific technical questions. I haven't thought deeply into it, but no, it shouldn't be very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach

**update** realized my answer could be a lot shorter, and more comprehensive (thanks to Nik Bougalis)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

static void compress_bitstring(std::string& str) { 
  std::stringstream ss;
  std::string cur_num;
  int count = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.size()-1; ++i){
    if (str[i] == str[i+1]){
      ++count;
      cur_num = str[i];
      if (i == str.size()-2){
        ss << count << cur_num;
      } else{
        if (count == 9){
          ss << count << cur_num;
          count = 0;
        }
      }
    } else if (count > 2){
        ss << count << cur_num;
        count = 1;
        if (i == str.size()-2){
          ss << str[i+1];
        }
    } else if (i != str.size()-2){
        for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j){
          ss << str[i];
        }
        count = 1;
    } else{
      ss << str[i] << str[i];
    }
  }
  str = ss.str();
}

static void decode_bitstring(std::string& str){
  int i = 0;
  int count;
  std::stringstream ss;
  while (i < str.size()){
    std::stringstream to_int;
    to_int << str[i];
    to_int >> count;
    if (count > 1){
      for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j){
        ss << str[i+1];
      }
      i = i + 2;
    } else{
      ss << str[i];
      ++i;
    }
  }
  str = ss.str();
}

int main(){
  std::string binary_num =  "0001011110010100000000000000000000000001";
  std::cout << binary_num << '\n';
  compress_bitstring(binary_num);
  std::cout << binary_num << '\n';
  decode_bitstring(binary_num);
  std::cout << binary_num << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

**edit 2** I also gave a decoder option.

output:

```
nero@ubuntu:~/learn$ ./lc
0001011110010100000000000000000000000001
301041001019090701
0001011110010100000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: You should add some code to catch run lengths longer than 9 characters, since those will be impossible to decode using this scheme.

Comment: I hadn't even considered that, thanks!

Comment: Also a (mostly stylistic) suggestion: checking `str[i]` against `str[i+1]` can make for tricky code; I would suggest you use a temporary variable to store the "run character" you are checking for, and compare it against `str[i]` only. Besides that, well done.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I wasn't sure if you meant to discard the attempt and warn the user, or try to keep with the same encoding idea, but I went with the attempt at generalization.  edit: Although this still fails when `count == 10`, but I'm not sure of a way to account for that, so maybe `runs > 9` just can't be accounted for.

Comment: There's no one "right" answer sometimes. Your attempt is fine, but there's an issue. Try compressing `0001011110010100000000000000000000000001` ;)

Comment: @seth You're answer `3010419020101` doesn't match the requested answer `30104100101`

Comment: @cdmh That answer refers to a *different* input string - where a run length of more than 9 characters was specified.

Comment: @NikBougalis sorry, reading too many answered, I just skipped to the 20101 at the end!

Comment: I updated my answer entirely after realizing I was making things too hard.

Comment: @seth: `00` should be coded as `00` not `20` according to the OP's Q.

Comment: `0001011110010100000000000000000000000001` should encode as `301041001019090701`, not `3010410010190909001` I think

Comment: okay, I updated my answer to also decode the string.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's my final answer, with compression of runlengths > 9 and refactoring duplicating code.

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(T t)
{
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << t;
    return str.str();
}

static void compress_bitstring(std::string& str)
{
    std::string result;
    int count = 0;
    char last = 0;

    auto add_to_result = [&]{
        if (count > 2)
            result += to_string(count) + last;
        else for (auto loop=0; loop<count; ++loop)
            result += last;
    };

    for (char ch : str)
    {
        if ((last == 0  ||  ch == last)  &&  count < 9)
            ++count;
        else {
            add_to_result();
            count = 1;
        }
        last = ch;
    }

    add_to_result();
    swap(result, str);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str("00010111100101");
    compress_bitstring(str);
    assert(str == "30104100101");

    str = "0001011110010100000000000000000000000001";
    compress_bitstring(str);
    assert(str == "301041001019090701");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(T t)
{
    std::ostringstream str;
    str << t;
    return str.str();
}

static void compress_bitstring(std::string& str)
{
    std::string result;
    int count = 0;
    char last = 0;
    for (char ch : str)
    {
        if (last == 0  ||  ch == last)
            ++count;
        else {
            if (count > 2)
                result += to_string(count) + last;
            else for (auto loop=0; loop<count; ++loop)
                result += last;
            count = 1;
        }
        last = ch;
    }

    if (count > 2)
        result += to_string(count) + last;
    else for (auto loop=0; loop<count; ++loop)
            result += last;

    swap(result, str);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str("00010111100101");
    compress_bitstring(str);
    assert(str == "30104100101");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code will generate a string that cannot be decoded if a run longer than 9 characters is present in the input. To be fair, however, the OP never specified what to do in that case.

Comment: True, but that wasn't mentioned in the question. There are lots of "problems" with the algorithm as asked, but I answered the question without offering a critique of the correctness of the question

Comment: you're right - I updated my post to reflect that, just as you posted your reply.

Comment: The `if (count > 2)` should really be factored out to avoid repetition of code. You could use a local lambda for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string compress1(std::string &s) {
    char c = s[0];
    int counter = 1;
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (c != s[i]) {
            if (counter > 2) ss << counter;
            if (counter == 2) ss << c;
            ss << c;
            counter = 0;
        }
        c = s[i];
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter > 2) ss << counter;
    if (counter == 2) ss << c;
    ss << c;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Output:

```
compress1("00010111100101"): 30104100101
compress1("000101111001011"): 301041001011
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I post my logic which may help you.

```
 #include<string.h>

int main(){
   char* str ="00010111100101";
   char* result = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
   int i = 0;
   char *q;
   char * p = str;
   result[i++] = str[0];

   do{
      q = strchr(str,str[0]=='0'?'1':'0'); //Searching for the opposite char.
     result[i++] = (q == '\0'? str+strlen(str) : q ) - p + '0'; // Storing the difference in result 
     str = p = q;   //updating str and p
   }while(q != '\0');
   result[i] = '\0';
   printf("Compressed Result = %s",result);
   return 0;
}
```

http://codepad.org/Qn8NEuB7

Comment: Uhm... first of all, this doesn't implement the compression algorithm the OP asked for - it implements some other algorithm. Second, it's horrible, practicaly incomprehensible code. And second, how can I *possibly* decode it it's output? This prints `3321` which has two possible decodings. Am I supposed to flip a coin and choose one or the other?

Comment: @Nik Bougalis ya I agree the code lags readability and doesnot implements the OP algorithm. But I am couldn't agree with your comment `practically incomprehensible code`. It is readable for the trained eyes though. While working with pointers in C, I think this is the fast and good approach. If I am wrong , correct me. Also, please show a sample how you would change the above code to make it more readable.